# Kivy v1.9.1 canvas.clear() not working as expected

Tags: python, kivy

I'm not really sure as to why the canvas isn't clearing.

The first build(self) implementation that has the parent variable is the one that works. The only thing I see different is that the second implementation is adding the Button widget to the MyPaintWidget instead of both of those widgets getting added to a default Widget class.

Very new to kivy i'm semi-familiar with python. I'd love an explanation.

```
from random import random
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line

'''
class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols=2
        self.add_widget(Label(text='User Name'))
        self.username=TextInput(multiline=False)a
        self.add_widget(self.username)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='password'))
        self.password=TextInput(password=True, multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.password)

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
            return LoginScreen()

'''
class MyPaintWidget(Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        color = (random(), 1, 1)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*color)
            d = 30.
            Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d / 2, touch.y - d / 2), size=(d, d))
            touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))
        print(touch)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]

class MyPaintApp(App):

#WHY ARE THESE TWO IMPLEMENTATIONS OF BUILD SO DIFFERENT?????
    '''
    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        self.painter = MyPaintWidget()
        clearbtn = Button(text='Clear')
        clearbtn.bind(on_release=self.clear_canvas)
        parent.add_widget(self.painter)
        parent.add_widget(clearbtn)
        return parent
    '''
    def build(self):
        self.painter = MyPaintWidget()
        clearbtn = Button(text='Clear')
        clearbtn.bind(on_release=self.clear_canvas)
        self.painter.add_widget(clearbtn)
        return self.painter

    def clear_canvas(self, obj):
        self.painter.canvas.clear()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Touches are dispatched down the widget tree, they enter at the root widget which must pass the touch down to its children (or fail to do so, if it wants).

Your `MyPaintWidget` class overrides on_touch_down but fails to pass the touch to its children, so the Button never receives the touch and never gets a chance to become pressed.

Add `return super(MyPaintWidget, self).on_touch_down(touch)` to the `MyPaintWidget.on_touch_down` to call the parent class method that automatically handles this for you.

Comment: So after I make that code change, the touches are recognized, but now after I press the clear button, the clear button "disappears"...  I wonder why

Comment: Is it because clear() clears the graphics instructions given by the child widget Button?